# Eclipse IDE - progress view show automatically when some progress

Tags: java, eclipse, progress-bar

Is there any setting somewhere in Eclipse IDE, to automatically popup/show progress view, when some operation in progress ?

Comment: There is view called Progress

Comment: I know, but I want to Eclipse pops out it automaticaly. I have this view in my views, but I would like to get focus to that view, when I start some operation. this was the question

Comment: Do you mean you are writing a plugin which needs to show progress?

Answer (score 4):

Go to Window > Preferences > General. In the General tab, uncheck the checkbox that says 'Always run in background'.

Once you do this, most operations will create a popup window showing progress of the operation, and you can also choose to push it to background if you wish to continue some other task. There is also a checkbox in the popup window which says 'Always run in background'. Never check that if you like seeing the popup window. If you do happen to check it by mistake, follow the above steps to restore the setting to your preference.

Comment: Liked the answer. Just to tell OP, this will be to annoying once it started auto popping and you will soon try to get rid of it. :)

Comment: The same happened with me. When I checked the 'Always run in background' option in the popup window by mistake, I tried hard to get it back. Finally when I figured out how to get it back, I just turned it off anyway within a couple of days. :P